# Como extraer un extracto de un texto con Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, xhtml

Tengo este sitio [inforegion.pe](http://www.inforegion.pe/257861/huancavelica-limpian-viviendas-en-anta-tras-inundacion/) que extraigo su fecha de publicación con xpath, para ello utilizo la extension de chrome que se llama : [xpath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl), en este caso mi xpath es: `//span[contains(@class, "box-date")]/text()`, como resultado me extrae : `Tocache - San Martín 01 febrero 2019 - 4:50 pm,`. Como se puede apreciar la fecha tiene un texto como:`Tocache - San Martín`, cómo podría hacer para que mi xpath me identifique del texto completo solo desde que empiece un numero?, en este caso seria `01` en adelante, cosa que el resultado seria como este: `01 febrero 2019 - 4:50 pm`, gracias

**NOTA**: Puede haber cualquier tamaño de texto antes del `01 febrero..`, por lo tanto no seria util por ejemplo con subcadenas fijas.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que tengas el texto lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar expresiones regulares. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo en Python:

```
patron = re.compile("(.*)\d{2} .* \d{4} - \d{1,2}:")
cadena = "Anta - Huancavelica 19 febrero 2019 - 6:10 pm"
resultado = patron.match(cadena).group(1).strip()
```

La expresion regular sigue el siguiente patron:

1. **(.*)\d{2}** Toma cualquier caracter seguido por 2 numeros y lo guarda en el grupo 1
2. **.* \d{4}** Encuentra cualquier cadena de caracteres, en este caso el mes, seguido por 4 numeros, el año.
3. **- \d{1,2}:** Identifica el comienzo de la hora de publicacion